# Do checkboxes default to unchecked in a PDF

Tags: pdf, checkbox, default

**[Edited with thanks to joelgeraci for his help understanding what the /V and /Opt keys in the field dictionary represent]**

I would like to extract the values of checkboxes within a PDF, using Python. I have some code for doing this, which seems to work fine and returns the field dictionary for every checkbox.

I have been looking at [the PDF standard](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf).

Under what circumstances can we say that a PDF checkbox is not checked? In my case I have checkboxes where all of /V, /DV, and /Opt are absent from the field dictionary. Are those to be interpreted as "not checked"? Is there a key in the field dictionary that only keeps track of whether there should be a tick in the box?

I'd love to have a reference to some specification document or documentation that says unequivocally, "Here are the circumstances where a checkbox should be interpreted as checked or not checked..."

Thanks so much for your help!

Here is some code that illustrates my current understanding of the implementation of checkboxes in PDFs, which you could maybe use to spot the errors in my thinking:

```py
def parse_checkbox(checkbox_dict: dict) -> tuple:
  '''
  Take a python dictionary representing the field dictionary
    of a PDF checkbox and say what the checkbox represents and
    whether it has been ticked.

  Parameters:
    checkbox_dict: a python dictionary representing the
      field dictionary of a PDF checkbox
      
  Returns:
    A tuple indicating what the checkbox represents and
      whether it was ticked
  '''
  def field_attribute(x):
    return checkbox_dict[x] if x in checkbox_dict else None

  opt, title, value, default = [field_attribute(a) for a in ['/Opt', '/T', '/V', '/DV']]

  assert opt is not None or title is not None
  name = opt if opt is not None else title

  if (value == '/Off' or \
      value is None and default == '/Off' or \
      value is None and default is None):
    return (name, 'unchecked')
  else:
    return (name, 'checked')
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not that simple. From the PDF specification...

> The V entry in the field dictionary (see Table 220) holds a name
> object representing the check box’s appearance state, which shall be
> used to select the appropriate appearance from the appearance
> dictionary.

In this case, the V entry has nothing to do with the value, it is used to set the appearance of the widget on the page.

Then...

> Beginning with PDF 1.4, the field dictionary for check boxes and radio
> buttons may contain an optional Optentry (see Table 227). If present,
> the Opt entry shall be an array of text strings representing the
> ***export value*** of each annotation in the field.

You may need to look at the Opt entry for the value and the value may not be "Yes" for checked but unchecked will always be "Off".

Comment: Sorry! I selected that this was the correct answer, but on reflection I don't think it answers my question. Sorry for the premature acceptance. My question is probably more clearly stated as, under what circumstances can we say that a PDF checkbox is not checked? In my case I have checkboxes where all of /V, /DV, and /Opt are absent. Are those to be interpreted as "not checked"? Is there a key in the field dictionary that only keeps track of wheether there should be a tick in the box? Can we derive something similar by checking a number of other keys?

Comment: That just seems wrong. What application created those PDf files? Anyway, you can look at the appearance dictionary for the widget and check the names of those. One of them should be "Off". If that's the only one, I think you can assume it's Off.

Comment: At first glance the spec says that the **V** value defines the state. Without a **V** value, therefore, the state is undefined and viewers can display whatever they want.

Comment: | That just seems wrong.

I know, right?

I see from the documentation on appearance dictionaries "Individual annotation handlers may ignore this entry and provide their own appearances"